# Do my Firebase rules expose each users private information?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The user needs to be able to load a list of the other users, which is why I have set the "read" to true. They should only be able to write within their own folder.

My question is, does this expose all of the users information to eachother? If a user has sensitive in one of their folders information, can this be stolen?

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
         ".read": true,
             "$userId": {
              ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the `".read": true` will give every user access to all the users data, since this rule is saying that we can read everything from the users node in your database.

Your rule only allows the current logged in user to write on its own node, but others users can't.